# php7 get specific value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php variable

```
  $thetypedmsg = serialize($bot->getMessage()->getPayload());
```

If I var_dump() the $thetypedmsg I am shown the below

```
  message: a:5:{s:6:"driver";s:3:"web";s:6:"userId";s:6:"2nwbuy";s:7:"message";s:6:"tester";s:10:"attachment";s:4:"null";s:11:"interactive";s:1:"0";}
```

So to get and show just the value that is entered as the "message" I am doing the below however it is showing nothing?

```
  $test = $message[0]['message'];
  echo "$test";
```

So how do i show what the value of "message" is?

Comment: don't use `serialize()` and you should be able to use the array

Comment: So if I do
  $messageis = $bot->getMessage()->getPayload();
    $themsg = $messageis[0]['message'];
  the value of $themsg is still nothing when it should be tester as shown in my above example array?

Answer (score 1):

The method `serialize()` transform data in one [serialized] string. The variable `$themsg` is not more an array, but a string. [Link for documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).

If you have an array, e.g. `['number'=>1234]` and use the `serialize` method, then you will have an serialized string, nothing for array.

In you case, you need to remove the `serialize` method for get: `$message[0]['message']`

```
$thetypedmsg = $bot->getMessage()->getPayload();
$test = $message[0]['message'];
echo $test; //  print: 'tester'.
```